# react-chartjs-2 candlestick chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

How can I implement candlestick chart on `react-chartjs-2`? This is my code:

```
import "chartjs-chart-financial";
import React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";

const CandlestickChart = () => {
    const data = {
        datasets: [
            {
                type: "candlestick",
                label: "Candlestick Chart",
                data: [{ t: new Date("2023-08-01"), o: 100, h: 120, l: 90, c: 110 }],
                borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                borderWidth: 2
            }
        ]
    };

    return <Chart type="candlestick" data={data} />;
};

export default CandlestickChart;
```

This is the error I receive:
`Error: "candlestick" is not a registered controller.`

I've double-checked if `chartjs-chart-financial` is installed. It is inside node_modules. I bumped all of the related packages to the latest versions.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install react react-chartjs-2 chartjs-chart-financial
```

And import

```
import "chartjs-chart-financial";
```